# Multiple sub-projects depending on the same library

Tags: cmake

I have a project `main_project`. It depends on two libraries - `libA` and `libB`, which in turn depend on `lib_common` each.

Graphically project's structure looks like this:

```
main_project
   |
   +-libA
   |   |
   |   +-CMakeLists.txt
   |
   +-libB
   |   |
   |   +-CMakeLists.txt
   |
   +-lib_common
   |   |
   |   +-CMakeLists.txt
   |
   +-CMakeLists.txt
```

Since `libA` uses `lib_common` it's pretty natural to call `add_subdirectory(lib_common)` inside `libA`'s `CMakeLists.txt`. But the `libB` also depends on `lib_common`. If I put it in a subdirectory again it will compile twice. And I don't want that. Also I want to keep all my subprojects clean and self-contained - that's why I don't want to put `lib_common` in top-level `main_project`'s `CMakeLists.txt` (because `lib_common` have nothing with `main_project`).

Which options do I have?

Comment: Dependencies are added with `add_dependency` or `target_link_libraries`. No need to call `add_subdirectory` from leaf CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would add one more abstraction level to your project structure:

- `app` - this is for executables and for everything that belongs to them,
- `lib` - libraries for the application.

The top-level `CMakeLists.txt` will only know that there is two different thing, the `app` sub-project and the `lib` sub-project. An example directory structure could look like follows:

```
FooProject
|-- app
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   `-- src
|       `-- foo.cpp
|-- CMakeLists.txt
`-- lib
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- libA
    |   |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |   |-- inc
    |   |   `-- bar.h
    |   `-- src
    |       `-- bar.cpp
    |-- libB
    |   |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |   |-- inc
    |   |   `-- baz.h
    |   `-- src
    |       `-- baz.cpp
    `-- lib_common
        |-- CMakeLists.txt
        |-- inc
        |   `-- common_tool.h
        `-- src
            `-- common_tool.cpp
```

The top-level `CMakeLists.txt` contains only the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(FooProject)

add_subdirectory(lib)
add_subdirectory(app)
```

The `app/CMakeLists.txt` should know that there is a `lib` folder from where you can include headers and that the executable depends on the `libA` and the `libB`:

```
project(foo)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib)
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src FOO_SOURCES)

add_executable(foo ${FOO_SOURCES})
add_dependencies(foo libA libB)
target_link_libraries(foo libA libB)

install(TARGETS foo RUNTIME DESTINATION bin ARCHIVE DESTINATION bin)
```

The `lib/CMakeLists.txt` exists to tie together the `libA`, `libB` and `lib_common`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

add_subdirectory(lib_common)
add_subdirectory(libA)
add_subdirectory(libB)
```

Let's say that `lib_common` has no dependencies, so the `lib/lib_common/CMakeLists.txt` won't see outside of its folder:

```
project(lib_common)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc)
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src LIBCOMMON_SOURCES)

add_library(lib_common ${LIBCOMMON_SOURCES})
```

In this example the `lib/libA/CMakeLists.txt` and `lib/libB/CMakeLists.txt` have almost identical content and only they deal with the `lib_common`:

```
project(libA)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..)
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src LIBA_SOURCES)

add_library(libA ${LIBA_SOURCES})
add_dependencies(libA lib_common)
target_link_libraries(libA lib_common)

install(TARGETS libA LIBRARY DESTINATION lib ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
```

In this example the `lib` sub-project is what you can call as *clean and self-contained*.

Answer (score 2):

I think this a fairly standard CMake solution:

```
# toplevel CMakeLists.txt
add_subdirectory(libA)
add_subdirectory(libB)
add_subdirectory(lib_common)
```

---

```
# libA CmakeLists.txt
add_library(libA ${LIBA_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(libA lib_common)
```

and similar for `libB`.

You do not have to call `add_subdirectory(lib_common)` before `add_subdirectory(libA)`, CMake handles the dependency management automatically.